# How to create single cucumber Extent Report when doing parallel cross browser execution

Tags: junit, cucumber, extentreports

When i am doing parallel execution using cucumber of multiple features file then it creates multiple cucumber extent reports. Could anyone please guide me how to generate a single cucumber Extent report of all the feature files instead of seperate- seperate exetent report.

Comment: Use the append parameter in constructor -- http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/2/java/#append-to-report. Though how multiple threads accessing the same report may lead to mixed up reports.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Grasshopper but could you please elaborate it or share the code if you have.